# Polygon in Android

Tags: android, polygon

Is there anyway I can use the Polygon class from java.awt in android?

Comment: in google maps there is but not android itself

Comment: so is it possible to do what i would like?

Answer (score 0):

No there is not.

Here there is a sample from Google to create a triangle using GL.

[triangle](http://code.google.com/p/apps-for-android/source/browse/Samples/OpenGLES/Triangle/src/com/google/android/opengles/triangle/?r=0599aa57c6891eceed3dca812523c015222a7331)

You can start from that to create your own classes.

Comment: is there no way I can use the Polygon class from java.awt?